# I am using Visual basic to export all images in xlsx file and rename them with the adjacent cell but it returns blank photos

Tags: excel, vba, xlsx

I found the following VBA code on "extendoffice.com" that offers me a way to export all images in excel file and rename them with the adjacent cell and it does export the photos and rename them but most of the photos are just blank. Here is the VBA code

```
Sub ExportImages_ExtendOffice()
'Updated by Extendoffice 20220308
    Dim xStrPath As String
    Dim xStrImgName As String
    Dim xImg As Shape
    Dim xObjChar As ChartObject
    Dim xFD As FileDialog
    Set xFD = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    xFD.Title = "Please select a folder to save the pictures" & " - ExtendOffice"
    If xFD.Show = -1 Then
       xStrPath = xFD.SelectedItems.Item(1) & "\"
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each xImg In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        If xImg.TopLeftCell.Column = 2 Then
        xStrImgName = xImg.TopLeftCell.Offset(0, -1).Value
        If xStrImgName <> "" Then
            xImg.Select
            
            Selection.Copy
            Set xObjChar = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(0, 0, xImg.Width, xImg.Height)
            With xObjChar
                .Border.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
                .Activate
                ActiveChart.Paste
                .Chart.Export xStrPath & xStrImgName & ".jpg"
                .Delete
            End With
        End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

And here is how the exported photos appear
[image]

what could be the problem ?

Comment: How come the filenames in your picture are "1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg" while your code (`.Chart.Export xStrPath & xStrImgName & ".png"`) shows that they should be "*.png" files?

Comment: @TomBrunberg My mistake. I've updated the above code.

Comment: Well, I cannot reproduce the error. Files are created and can be seen in file explorer (View - Large Icons) with the format indicated by either `.png` or `.jpg`.

Comment: @TomBrunberg Yes, they are. but the problem is that they are created as empty blank photos!! just a white background

Comment: instead of using xImage.Select() followed by Selection.Copy, can you use xImage.CopyPicture() method ?

Comment: You say: *but **most** of the photos are just blank* How are the photos that show up different from those that doesn't show up?

Comment: Try manually changing a saved file's type to different image formats and see if that works. Firstly, make sure you can see file types by changing windows settings: https://www.howtogeek.com/205086/beginner-how-to-make-windows-show-file-extensions/

Comment: I tried stepping through the code by pressing F8 for a few times and the output photos are fine, no blank photos. Still don't know the problem though but i guess that will do for now. Thank you every one.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot reproduce, and neither imagine what may be the reason for your problem.

Image of Excel:

[image]

Image of Explorer:

[image]

As you see I tried with output formats `.jpg` and `.png`. The original files were `.bmp`, therefore the strange file names.

Comment: I tried stepping through the code by pressing F8 for a few times and the output photos are fine, no blank photos. Thank you for help.